# Chilkat PDF Sign Custom Fields

Tags: pdf, chilkat

Hello i use Chilkat PDF to sign my PDF and i want to know if it is possible
change label "Signature2" to a custom text, and fill details of signature, with location and reason?

Thanks

Exemple: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QjYH.png

Comment: did you take a look for this example: https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/sign_pdf_simple.asp and here: https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/pdf_signatures.asp ??